# Abusive language in Suggested Edit

Tags: discussion, flags, suggested-edits, offensive

During review I found some bad words written in a suggested edit. I have rejected that edit as "invalid".

I don't want to name the user who did this but how should I deal with this situation? Should I go for a custom reason of rejection, and if so, what should I mention there? or did I take the correct action?

Please guide me.

Comment: What you did was correct -- you rejected the edit. I don't think we have a way to flag reviews yet, so there's not much more you can do on that side.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi So what I did was proper than I will keep doing that if I found same things in future :).Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I suppose you're referring to [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4898412)? I have no idea what that means in the language it's written in, but whether it's offensive or not, it should be rejected on an English-only site. And though Frederic is right about there being no way to flag suggested edits, even if there were, it wouldn't help in this case—the user is an anonymous one.

Comment: @CodyGray Well no it's not that one the edit about which I was talking has some abusive words written in local language but yes as you have said any Non-English Edit must be rejected than I'll do the same in future.My concern was to find some other way to deal with this stuff nothing more than that :).

Comment: @CodyGray It's turk and basically says: I had a similiar problem, this code solved it.

Comment: @CodyGray : translation(translate.google.com) for it "My Rotation App when I was going back into the My First Page Page Refresh Meat However, because this is the codes solved my problem."

Comment: Remember a custom reason if only for the benefit of the editor - and if they defaced a post guaranteed they won't read it. Better that you get a quick rejection in on the off chance that other people are approving it.

Comment: @TAsk AFAIK it's fine to "name and shame", and without pointing at an example people can only give hypothetical answers (or so far, comments).

Comment: @OGHaza Thanks for your response and specifically thank you for the clarification on Custom Reason.

Comment: @AD7six Yes I agree but at that point of time that didn't come in to my mind and after rejection I thought why not to ask regarding this on Meta.

Comment: Agreed to @FrédéricHamidi. I had encountered abusive [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4872882) (From OP itself). The OP Changed his content (with code) to abusive content and I flagged the question with moderator's attention. At the end, the OP's account has been suspended and deleted.

Comment: Isn't there an option that indicates an edit is **vandalism** when you reject it? I think that applies to abusive language.

Comment: @Glenn-- what a nice guy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We're talking about [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4872882).

Pretty straightforward:

1. Reject the edit as vandalism.
2. Flag the original question for moderator attention, explaining what happened and linking to the suggested edit.  They'll always want to follow up on things like this.

Answer (score 4):

The edit you mention (if it is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4898412)) was made by an anonymous user in another language. It is my understanding that anonymous edits are always to be seen as more suspicious, and since the paragraph was in a language other than English, it was not acceptable.

As far as abusive language is concerned (which I first confused for *offensive* language) I think the same rules apply here as in any self-respecting community - if not more so.

To conclude with a **tl;dr**: Well rejected.

Comment: @Zizouz, wow, adding two spaces, what a so very good use of your time and ours. Could you explain that edit? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi what? I wasn't even on an hour ago? That's really strange...

Comment: @Zizouz, ouch. Unless you're able to edit posts in your sleep, it may be time for an overall password change. You know the drill.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi someone vandalized this too: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307287/can-we-pleeeeaaseee-see-revision-histories-in-suggested-edit-queues

Comment: @Zizouz, okay, it's official then. Time to change all your passwords. Sorry. Don't forget to log out on all devices also.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Well that gave me a good head-scratching session.